# Reserved SQL keyword 'User' is not permitted as simple type name

Tags: java, spring-roo

When I gave the roo command

```
entity --class  ~.domain.User
```

in the roo shell, I got

```
Reserved SQL keyword 'User' is not permitted as simple type name
```

What I want to know is that, is there a way to gave alias name to the entity ? Because I do have a couple of entities which name are not permitted as above. Or is there a way to overcome this kind of problem ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try to add the  `--permitReservedWords` option to the entity command.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1502

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the entity name, but keep the table name:

```
entity --class ~.domain.FooUser --table user
```

I would think there is a way to quote all sql identifiers, but I don't know that much about Roo.